# Additional topics in ROS kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- I use the rostopic command on my ROS and get the following output:

had@had-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs0xxx:~$ rostopic list

/rosout

/rosout_agg

- I'm looking at a tutorial and they also use "rostopic list" but there are more topics in it:

/gazebo/set_model_state

/initialpose

/joint_state

/map

/map_metadata

/mobile_base/commands/velocity

/mobile_base_nodelet_manager/bond

/move_base_simple/goal

/odom

/rosout

/rosout_agg

/slam_gmapping/entropy

/tf

/tf_static

etc...

=> So please tell me if I am missing something and if so, how should I add those topics?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381670/additional-topics-in-ros-kinetic/) by [hoangdung2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/74409/hoangdung2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They must be launching few other nodes and then using the rostopic list command.

---

Originally posted by [rugved](https://answers.ros.org/users/75152/rugved/) with karma: 26 on 2021-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hoangdung2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/74409/hoangdung2000/) on 2021-07-04**:
thank you ,

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `rostopic list` command is used to display the current topics that are currently being published by the nodes they are running. So if there are no nodes publishing any topic, there would not be any additional topics displayed in the list.

You can try cloning the example repository into your current workspace & running the examples: https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials. (Make sure to compile the packages & source the workspace beforehand.)

---

Originally posted by [photon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28317/photon/) with karma: 68 on 2021-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hoangdung2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/74409/hoangdung2000/) on 2021-07-04**:
thank you very much